# WPF Button ... Is there a way to set a background color separately from a Style declaration

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 50 buttons on a page, so I declared a Style that would declare a border and IsPressed behavior that applies to ALL buttons.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <statusModule:BooleanToBackgroundColorConverter x:Key="BooleanToBackgroundColor"/>
    <Style x:Key="ValveButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="border" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderThickness"  Value="3" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The issue I have is that EACH button background color is controlled via a separate ViewModel property, such as

```
 <Button Content="Deflection Gas Valve" Background="{Binding Path=OpenDeflectionGasValve, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToBackgroundColor}, Mode=OneWay}"  Style="{StaticResource ValveButtonStyle}"
 <Button Content="Purge Gas Valve" Background="{Binding Path=OpenPurgeGasValve, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToBackgroundColor}, Mode=OneWay}"  Style="{StaticResource ValveButtonStyle}"
```

and another button background binding would be to a completely different ViewModel property.

If I assign a Style to the button, then the Background setting as declared above has no effect.

Is there a way that I can use a Style for ALL buttons but declare a Background value as shown above for each.

Comment: Paste the style mentioned in order to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `ConroleTemplate`, you need respect the original `Background` property of the `TextBox` control, via `TemplateBinding`. 
Each TextBox property (of apparance) that is not mentioned in your template becomes meaningless.

so change

```
Background="Transparent"
```

to:

```
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```

Now, the background will be affected by the value in the `background` TextBox property.
and for set **default** value to background property, set the color in the style via setter:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
```

Comment: PERFECT!! Works Great! Thanks much!